# Link two excel workbook located in different computers

Tags: networking, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2003

I have two excel workbook
The first one located in one computer (i.e. "\192.168.7.1\Shared\book1.xls")
The second one in another computer (i.e.  "\192.168.7.2\Shared\book2.xls")

With both spreadsheet opened in the relative computer, I want to link the `Book1!A1` cell on the second one, then any time the Book1!A1 cell change the book2 refresh the values...

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want the functionality of changes updating quickly, then you will have to use a version of office that supports collaboration this way (like Excel Web Apps) and then use different spreadsheets or something similar to do the references.

If you want to skip the real-time (or anything like it time) update, you can use: `='\192.168.7.1\Shared\[book1.xls]Book1'!A1`
to access a cell in the other document. Note that this data will only get loaded when the files opens.

In short, excel was not meant to do what you want it to do, but these workarounds might help.

Comment: Thank you I used the link like the one you wrote, but I didn't know about the fact that this link won't update... do you think it works if I use a VBA macro for the timing?

Comment: No, the timing cannot be solved using excel.

Answer (score -1):

Try uploading the file to Google Docs. 
It will save automatically and so the updates are available seconds after you make them.
It supports multiple users, and the only difference would be that all users have to be online to access and update it.

Comment: This question has already a best answer. You are also not fixing the problem, since you are just promoting Google Docs above Excel. The actual problem is to handle data between two different sheets.